# Como pegar os dados selecionados de um checkbox pelo laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Olá, tudo bem?

Tenho o seguinte formulario:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="stock_options">Opções de Estoque</label>
    @foreach($stockOptions as $stockOption)
    <div class="form-check col-md-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="stockOption" value="{{$stockOption->stock_option_id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="stockOption">{{$stockOption->name}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stockOptionQuantity" placeholder="Quantidade">
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

Isso está dentro de um cadastro do produto onde estou tentando cadastrar as opções de estoque, ele selecionaria as opção de estoque e colocaria quanto é necessário daquela opção para fazer o produto.
No momento não estou sabendo como pegar apenas os "Inputs" selecionados e a quantidade deles para ser pegado no create do laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na função pra onde a rota dessa requisição está sendo direcionada, certamente store, você deve pegar os dados da variável $request, podendo atribuir os valores a uma outra variável:

`$inputs = $request->all();`

ou pegando um campo em específico:

`$stockOption = $request->input('stockOption');`

Para testar o que está atribuído a uma variável você pode utilizar a função dd():

`dd($stockOption);`

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre requisições na documentação do Laravel, segue o link:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests

Comment: Oh, muito obrigado, deu certo desse jeito. Uma coisa que aprendi no emprego que funfou é colocar o nome dos inputs como "stockAction[]" ae quando pego os valores eles estão dentro de um Array na controller, meio gambis mas funfa